# temporarily cast a unique_ptr to a raw pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, unique-ptr

I have a question regarding smart pointers.
Is it possible to temporarily cast a smart pointer to a raw pointer?
For example:

`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<monster>> all_monsters` to `std::vector <monster*> all_monsters`;?
I have been looking everywhere on the internet but can't find a method

I have a `std::vector <monster*> all_monsters` and I have another vector called `std::vector <monster*> monsters` which has objects that should be deep copied into all_monsters.
So I use this for loop to do so

```
  for (unsigned i=0; i < monsters.size(); i++) 
{            all_monsters.push_back(new monster(monsters[i]->getMonster(),monsters[i]->getCost(),monsters[i]->getType()));
     }
```

However I don't want to be manually deleting the objects so I want to use a unique pointer.
That's why I changed my vector to
    `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<monster>> all_monsters;`
and my for loop to

```
for(unsigned i = 0; i < monsters.size(); i++)
{

       all_monsters.push_back(std::make_unique<monster>(all_monsters[i]->getName(),all_monsters[i]->getManaCost(),all_monsters[i]->getType()));

}
```

but I have a function that only takes `std::vector <monster*>` as input (which can not be changed) that's why I want to temporarily cast the shared pointer to a raw pointer.
Am I thinking too complicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly get a single raw pointer from a single `std::unique_ptr`, using the [`get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) member function.

But you cannot safely cast a `std::vector` of one type to a `std::vector` of a different type.

So if the other function's interface can't be changed, you'll unfortunately need an extra step to build its `vector` argument:

```
std::vector<monster*> tmp_monsters;
std::transform(all_monsters.begin(), all_monsters.end(),
               back_inserter(tmp_monsters),
               [](const std::unique_ptr<monster>& mon_in) { return mon_in.get(); });
other_function(tmp_monsters);
```

Comment: I get the error ` conversion candidate of type 'monster **(*)(const std::unique_ptr<monster*>`

Comment: Whoops, I missed the `&` in the lambda.

Comment: error: `conversion candidate of type 'monster **(*)(const std::unique_ptr<monster *> &)'` really have no Idea why

Comment: @momonosuke There was an extra asterisk, Try the latest version.

Comment: @JaMiT thanks a lot it works now. I have a question to the code: Even though the values of all_monsters is stored in the temp , how does it free the memory in temp_monsters?

Comment: @momonosuke The memory management still falls to `all_monsters`. The `tmp_monsters` vector is valid only as long as `all_monsters` is unchanged. The idea is that right after the call to `other_function()` you forget that `tmp_monsters` exists.

Comment: @JaMiT so if I want to delete objects (using push_back) should I use it on tmp_monsters or all_monsters?

Comment: @momonosuke The idea is that right after the call to `other_function()` you forget that `tmp_monsters` exists. You cannot modify something that you've forgotten about. 1) Declare `tmp_monsters`. 2) Populate `tmp_monsters` using `std::transform`. 3) Call `other_function()`. 4) Never use `tmp_monsters` again. Maybe this should all be done in a wrapper so that you're not tempted to consider such things?

Comment: oh ok . Because the function that I call will shuffle the object pointers(like a deck).

Comment: So if I modify temp and never use it again will it modify the original?

Comment: Oh. No, if the other function takes the vector by reference and changes its order or size, that will have no effect on the order or size of `tmp_monsters`. This would be pretty nasty to work around. (But if all it does is shuffle the vector, maybe look at `std::shuffle` instead.)

Comment: @aschepler but would it have an effect on all_monsters? If I call the function with tmp_monstets?

Comment: No, building `tmp_monsters` as shown is not useful for making any changes to `all_monsters`. It would only be useful for a function that took `const std::vector<monster*>&`.

Comment: @momonosuke Sorry, it looks like you left out a key piece in your question, hence got an answer inadequate for your situation. You wrote *"I have a function that only takes `std::vector <monster*>` as input "* but did not mention that this parameter is *also an output parameter*. Since the question you did ask is valid and has an answer, you might want to start a new question that better describes your situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know I am spamming the comments but what could happen if I still use tmp_monsters even though it's not meant to be used again?

Comment: Nothing bad. JaMiT just meant that using it again would probably not be useful. It will have the shuffled raw pointers, if that's any help.

Comment: @momonosuke There are a few potential pitfalls. If you remove an element from `all_monsters` (thus freeing the associated `monster` object), then `tmp_monsters` is left with a dangling pointer. It's just simpler (and more robust) to go with a "don't use again" guideline than to make sure you avoid all the pitfalls. If you only need a single iteration through the shuffled pointers to get your desired result, that would probably work out. As advice, keep it as simple as you can.